# PreloadJS + Typescript

Tags: this, typescript, easeljs

I have been stuck for 4 days so it is going on SO!

Please reference the PreloadJS Definitions:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/preloadjs/preloadjs.d.ts

From line 26.

My question is, how do you addEventListener in typescript while also binding it to the class scope?

imagine (semi psudo):

```
class Test
{
     private _loader:createJS.AssetLoader;

     constructor()
     {
          this._loader = new createJS.AssetLoader();
          this._loader.addEventListener(???????????);
          this._loader.load();
     }

     onLoadComplete(???): ???
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: This should be helpful to understand `this` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using TypeScript 0.9.1.0:

```
class Test
{
     private _loader: createJS.AssetLoader;

     constructor()
     {
          this._loader = new createJS.AssetLoader();
          this._loader.addEventListenerthis.onLoadComplete);
          this._loader.load();
     }

     onLoadComplete = () =>
     {
        console.log(this.whatever);
     };
}
```

The important part here is using the member initialization syntax (`member = value`) for `onLoadComplete` and using a fat arrow lambda expression (`() => { ... }`) for the function. This will correctly capture the `this` context in the callback.

Comment: Just to reiterate what Ryan has already mentioned. This syntax is *new* to 0.9.1. So you need at least this version